# Unable to click on blog listings in mobile view/device

Tags: wordpress, blogs, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a blog [TheSEOGuy](https://www.theseoguy.in) everything on desktop version is working fine but when I open the blog in mobile, I am not able to click on blog listings. I have 6 blog categories and I have written few blogs under each category. I am able to open the categories from the main menu but not able to click and open the blogs from the listing. I tried adjusting the default theme options to tried switching the excerpts only, experts with thumbnail and full posts but nothing works.

Comment: I have just visited your website. The primary sidebar's `position` property (currently set to `relative` ) is causing the issue. Set it to `static` to make content accessible (but check if that has any impact on other elements) OR give the `primary` container a higher `z-index`.

Comment: Hi @Ferris thanks for the help. I was fixing the issue but then I realized it's not about primary sidebar. It was jetpack plugin clashing with spectra so I removed spectra from wp-include folder.